# Design carbon surfaces on printed circuit boards with Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I am in the process of creating a circuit board that will later be assembled with conductive rubber for the buttons. For the contact areas I found that carbon is used (please correct me if I am wrong).

How can I design such contact surfaces with a tool like Eagle so that they can later be printed by a manufacturer?

Comment: You could create a new layer just for that purpose. Then later you can select only that layer to run the CAM job.

Comment: In Altium  you would use a layer pair so that if the switch is flipped to the other side, the carbon (or glue dot or peelable solder mask) follows. If Eagle does not have that capability you can just do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've now taken the tFinish layer for the carbon mask of eagle and created an additional cam job.